# Why new Date() with `T17:00:00.000Z` is returning the next date?

Tags: javascript, date

When I try this `new Date('2015-01-25T17:00:00.000Z')` it will returning the next date `Jan 26 2015 00:00:00`, this is an expected behaviour for me, but why it is like this?

Is there any explanation from this js behaviour when using TZ with value of OO:OO:OO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Z` at the very end means "Zulu Time" which is another word for UTC.

The result you see in your console is the time in your current timezone. You are probably 5 hours ahead of UTC.

If you remove the `Z`, the output you get is the same as what you put in, because Javascript will use local time by default.

Answer (score 1):

UTC (Zulu) time is '2015-01-25T17:00:00.000Z'. The local time in Jakarta is UTC+7: `Jan 26 2015 00:00:00`.

See [Time in Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indonesia) and [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).